# How to add zero values to a grouping for subsequent normal subtraction Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file from which I get the data and do the grouping.
Which looks something like this

| Time | Operation | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10:00:00 | Up | 40 |
| 10:00:00 | Down | 24 |
| 10:00:01 | Up | 4 |
| 10:00:01 | Down | 54 |
| 10:00:02 | Down | 22 |
| 10:00:03 | Up | 12 |
| 10:00:03 | Down | 11 |

To do this, I use

```
df = pd.read_csv(Ex_Csv, usecols=['Time','Count','Operation'], parse_dates=[0])
df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.floor('S', 0).dt.time
df2 = df.groupby(['Operation', 'Time']).sum()
```

After I do the subtraction

```
out = df2.loc['Up']-df2.loc['Down']
```

I expected that if the values for example 'up' as at 10:00:02 did not come that it would be equal to 0 and I would get 0 - 22 and I get this

| Time | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 10:00:00 | 16 |
| 10:00:01 | -50 |
| 10:00:02 | -22 |
| 10:00:03 | 1 |

But I get this

| Time | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 10:00:00 | 16 |
| 10:00:01 | -50 |
| 10:00:02 |  |
| 10:00:03 | 1 |

Is it possible to somehow equate the value of 'up' or 'down'   to zero if it didn 't come ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""Time;Operation;Count
10:00:00;Up;40
10:00:00;Down;24
10:00:01;Up;4
10:00:01;Down;54
10:00:02;Down;22
10:00:03;Up;12
10:00:03;Down;11
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=';')
pd.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time).dt.time
df.groupby(['Operation', 'Time']).sum()

df2 = pd.pivot(df, index='Time', columns='Operation', values='Count').fillna(0).astype(int)
df2.Up - df2.Down
```

Output:

```
Time
10:00:00    16
10:00:01   -50
10:00:02   -22
10:00:03     1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I get the error 'Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'

Answer (score 1):

Try to pivot your dataframe then fill null values by 0 then compute the diff:

```
out = (df.pivot('Time', 'Operation', 'Count').fillna(0).diff(1, axis=1)['Up']
         .rename('Count').reset_index())
print(out)

# Output
       Time  Count
0  10:00:00   16.0
1  10:00:01  -50.0
2  10:00:02  -22.0
3  10:00:03    1.0
```

Before the `diff`, your dataframe looks like:

```
>>> df.pivot('Time', 'Operation', 'Count').fillna(0)
Operation  Down    Up
Time                 
10:00:00   24.0  40.0
10:00:01   54.0   4.0
10:00:02   22.0   0.0
10:00:03   11.0  12.0
```

Safe way:

```
out = df.pivot('Time', 'Operation', 'Count').fillna(0)
out = pd.Series(out['Up']-out['Down'], index=out.index, name='Count').reset_index()
print(out)

# Output
       Time  Count
0  10:00:00   16.0
1  10:00:01  -50.0
2  10:00:02  -22.0
3  10:00:03    1.0
```

Comment: I get the error 'Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'

Comment: You have some duplicates for a same (Time, Operation). What do you want  to do if you have 2 rows like (10:00:00, Up) with 2 different values? Do you want to sum them before?